#  detect typing in an edit control

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, api

**Edit:** Nevermind! the code below doesn't work but when I copy and paste it from the website, it works fine.

I tried what [**this**](http://www.apitalk.com/windows-Programming/Create-A-Textbox-And-Track-Change-Event-In-Winapi.html) website told me but it didn't work. Anywhay, probably doing something pretty nooby.

```
int editid = 5654;
HWND edit;

//int WINAPI wWinMain
WNDCLASS wc;
wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
wc.lpszClassName = L"class name";




    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    0,
    L"Class name",
    L"Copy N Paste",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_VISIBLE,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, 10,
    885, 484,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL
    );



edit = CreateWindowEx(
    0,
    L"EDIT",
    NULL,
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE |  ES_LEFT,
    20, 12,
    480, 22,
    hwnd,
    (HMENU)editid,
    hInstance,
    NULL
);

// LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc
switch(uMsg) {
case WM_COMMAND:
    if(HIWORD(wParam) == EN_CHANGE && LOWORD(wParam)==editid) { // this is
        //supposed to detect a change event in the edit control
        MessageBox(0, L"Doesnt Work!", L"failure", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code from your application? Did the sample code work for you?

Comment: BTW, use SetWindowLongPtr instead of SetWindowLong. It'll help you develop 32/64 bit agnostic software. Also, what did you put in the curly braces where it tells you to put your code?

Comment: The example on website is just working fine.

Comment: Well, I it works fine when I copy and paste it exactly from the website. Mabye its the switch statement.

Answer (score 3):

You can handle WM_COMMAND, check the lparam for the HWND of your control and see if the HIWORD of your wparam isn't a focus command.

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    if((HWND)lparam == hwndmycontrol) {
        if(HIWORD(wparam) != EN_SETFOCUS && HIWORD(wparam) != EN_KILLFOCUS) {
            //triggered on keypress
        }        
    }
```

edit: Make sure you check if wparam is IDOK (which means the user hit enter).

Answer (score 0):

The notification is sent to the parent of the edit. You are probably listening to the notification in the edit control's window proc.